# Altered `bcdedit` and now Windows 10 won't boot

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, boot, grub

I have dual boot on my Surface Pro 3, Windows 10 primary (was installed first) and Ubuntu Budgie (secondary). During the installation, `GRUB2` was installed as well. Following the guide [here](https://itsfoss.com/no-grub-windows-linux/), I entered

```
bcdedit /set "{bootmgr}" path EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi
```

When I power up the Surface, I see the GRUB menu, from which I can choose `Ubuntu` and it boots fine. But, before the command above, I used to be able to press `Esc` and type `exit` to exit GRUB and boot Windows 10. Since after that command, I can no longer access Windows 10. Now, when I exit GRUB, it just restarts the computer back to the GRUB menu, and if I do it again it turns off the computer!

PLEASE do **not** direct me to [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1368251/i-messed-up-my-bcdedit-and-now-i-cant-boot-into-windows-10) or [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi), as I have already read those posts and tried their solutions. Additionally, I have tried the following commands with no help:

```
bcdedit /default {ntldr}
bcdedit /set "{bootmgr}" path EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi
```

*Please tell me there is a way to get Windows back other than re-install*

[Here is an image of `bcdedit` command from Command Prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bzr9N.jpg)

Comment: I run into the same issue, but noe I couldn't access windows neither ubuntu.. what do you think I can do?

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out editing boot configurations wasn't the issue--the issues was the BitLocker preventing me from booting to Windows. I used the Command Prompt to manually disabled BitLocker so it wouldn't yell at me when I boot Windows through GRUB. Commands used

```
manage-bde -status   #returns list of volumes and whether they are encrypted or not
manage-bde -unlock (volume name, example C:) -rp (48 digit recovery code)
manage-bde -protectors -disable (volume name, example C:)
```